# Referring to a chapter of a paper

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing

In my references (the library is automatically produced by Mendeley) I have a paper "Abc", which I refer to quite a lot. At one point I need to refer to a specific section in this paper (or a page, it doesn't matter). Is there a way to do that? Something like: "in Abc, section 3.2" or "in Abc, page 15".

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\library.bib}
@book{abc,
  author = {Alphabet, A.},
  year = {1990},
  title = {Abc},
  publisher = {My Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

I think that the model described in \cite{abc}, chapter 3.2, is awesome.

\bibliography{\library.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `\cite[page 15]{abc}` close enough to what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by @samcarter:

```
\cite[page 15]{abc}.
```

Comment: Just a note on our usual policy: Usually we ask the person who solved the issue (and if it was just in the comments) to provide an answer.

Comment: Sorry, all credit goes to samcarter, I'm not sure how to fix it.